# Need tab delimited values

Tags: excel, tabs, cell

Hi I have these numbers

1 2 3 4 5

for displaying these i have used echo "\t" between each numbers but when I am pasting these numbers in excel all are coming in a single cell.

I need 1 in the first cell, 2 in the second cell and so on.

Please suggest what to do for this.

Comment: What language?  IS this on a web site you need to export the numbers in this fashion?

Comment: If its a website you create it like an html table....Excel respects it and shows it accordingly.

Comment: Does it paste with or without the space between the numbers?

Comment: In php..I am using currently ..
echo $i."\t" format..

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting the values into excel you can use the 'Text to Columns' functionality to split the values apart based on tabs.

1. Choose the column you've pasted the numbers into
2. Go to the 'Data' ribbon menu
3. Click the 'Text to Columns' button.
4. In the resulting dialog under 'original data type' choose 'delimited'
5. Click 'Next'
6. Make sure 'Tab' is selected under 'delimiters'
7. Click finish.

Alternatively if you save the results of your program as a file with a .txt extension and then open that file with excel it should automatically pop up the 'Text Import Wizard' where you can tell excel to open the file as a tab delimited file.